# Flutter dart:118:33: Error: The argument type 'HTMLStyleElement' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'JSAny'

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am facing the below Flutter SDK error while importing an existing Flutter project.

```
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart:118:33: Error: The argument type
'HTMLStyleElement' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'JSAny'.
 - 'HTMLStyleElement' is from 'package:web/src/dom/html.dart'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto your dart file in Flutter SDK path as below:
\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets_platform_selectable_region_context_menu_web.dart

line: 118

change:

```
web.document.head!.append(styleElement);
```

with:

```
web.document.head!.append(styleElement.toJSBox);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. This saves my day :) 
But after implement this my web page is shows only loading , nothing else. Any idea about that why is happening?

Comment: @Developer do you fix it yet

Comment: @Sras yes , fixing.

Comment: @Developer how did you fix?

Comment: @Sras May I know that which flutter sdk you are using?
Because I updated my flutter sdk from 3.16.4 to 3.16.9 and in latest version everything worked fine as expected without changing below line.

web.document.head!.append(styleElement);

Also please make sure that you have excellent connection of network :)

Comment: @Developer I have the lastest 3.16.6 . after flutter clean. it seems to be okay

Comment: @Developer it may be late but your internet connection is causing delays otherwise incompatibility in versions for Flutter, Gradle, Kotlin, and Java usually impacts system response.

Comment: @AbdulSaleem yes , in 4G internet connection , my website is not load , so I check with 5G connection , and it works